# Contribution of 3 groups of data to an overall PDF

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I have a time series that is comprised of 3 subgroups. I want to know how I can calculate the contribution of each of these subgroups to the overall PDF.

```
g1 = {5.2527, 4.72782, 4.38049, 3.49102, 3.72147, 3.33897, 3.95193, 3.569,4.40854, 3.79908, 4.5764, 5.0339, 5.22894, 5.4027, 3.02539, 3.22868, 3.33291, 4.21609, 4.25765, 4.4448}
g2 = {3.83361, 3.86359, 3.81128, 4.1451, 3.8751, 3.80214, 6.21452, 4.15563, 4.54328, 4.3105, 4.45165, 4.61335, 4.41786, 4.62966, 4.88515}
g3 = {5.23026, 5.7992, 5.23549, 5.54506, 5.83686, 4.79847, 4.80319, 5.40646, 5.34246, 5.44923}


Histogram[Join[g1, g2, g3], {0.2}, "PDF",
FrameLabel -> {"Lag (ms)", "Weighted PDF"},
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300,
ChartStyle -> Gray,
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None]]
```

[image]

Now, like a stacked bar chart, how I can show the contribution of each of those groups to this PDF?

Answer (score 2):

```
g1 = {5.2527, 4.72782, 4.38049, 3.49102, 3.72147, 3.33897, 3.95193, 3.569, 4.40854, 3.79908, 4.5764, 5.0339, 5.22894, 5.4027, 3.02539, 3.22868, 3.33291, 4.21609, 4.25765, 4.4448};
g2 = {3.83361, 3.86359, 3.81128, 4.1451, 3.8751, 3.80214, 6.21452, 4.15563, 4.54328, 4.3105, 4.45165, 4.61335, 4.41786, 4.62966, 4.88515};
g3 = {5.23026, 5.7992, 5.23549, 5.54506, 5.83686, 4.79847, 4.80319, 5.40646, 5.34246, 5.44923};

joined = Join[g1, g2, g3];
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[joined, {0.2}];
contrib = Last[HistogramList[#, {bins}]] & /@ {g1, g2, g3};
BarChart[Transpose[contrib], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[bins, Below, Rotate[#, Pi/2.4] &], None}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"g1", "g2", "g3"}]
```

[image: stacked histogram]

And you can get the proportions each dataset contributes like this if you just want the numbers:

```
Table[MapThread[
   If[#2 > 0, #1/#2, 0] &, {contrib[[k]], Total[contrib]}], {k, 
   Length[contrib]}] // Grid
```

```
1   1   1   1   1/6 0   3/4 1/2 1/4 0   1   2/5 1/4 0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   5/6 1   1/4 1/2 1/2 1/2 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1/4 1/2 0   3/5 3/4 1   1   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `"Count"` as the height function, you can simply use the option `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"` with input `{g1, g2, g3}`:

```
hist123 = Histogram[{g1, g2, g3}, {.2}, "Count", ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLegends -> {"g1", "g2", "g3"}];

histall = Histogram[Join[g1, g2, g3], {0.2}, "Count", 
   ChartStyle -> FaceForm[], ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}]];

Show[hist123, histall, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Lag (ms)", "Count"}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

With `"PDF"` as the height value, we can rescale the bar heights. Since this scaling is linear we can simply change the tick labels using `` Charting`FindTicks ``:

```
{bl, pdfall} = HistogramList[Join[g1, g2, g3], {0.2}, "PDF"];

cntsall = BinCounts[Join[g1, g2, g3], {bl}];

Show[hist123, histall, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Lag (ms)", "Weighted PDF"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, 
 FrameTicks ->
    {{Charting`FindTicks[{0, Max@cntsall}, {0, Max@pdfall}], Automatic}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

or using `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` with scaling function `heightF`:

```
heightF = Rescale[#, {0, Max @ cntsall}, {0, Max @ pdfall}] &;


Show[hist123, histall, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Lag (ms)", "Weighted PDF"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, 
 FrameTicks -> 
   {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{ InverseFunction[heightF], heightF}], Automatic}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use the function `heightF` as a custom height function in the third argument of `Histogram`. Using `heightF` or `"PDF"` in the third argument for combined data gives the same bar heights:

```
Row[{Histogram[Join[g1, g2, g3], {0.2}, "PDF", ImageSize -> Medium, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ChartStyle -> FaceForm[], 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}]],
  Histogram[Join[g1, g2, g3], {0.2}, heightF[#2]&, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ChartStyle -> FaceForm[], 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Use `heightF` in both histograms and use `Show` to combine the two:

```
Show[Histogram[{g1, g2, g3}, {.2}, heightF[#2]&, 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Lag (ms)", "Weighted PDF"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, ChartLegends -> {"g1", "g2", "g3"}], 
 Histogram[Join[g1, g2, g3], {0.2}, heightF[#2]&, 
   ChartStyle -> FaceForm[], ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wean yourself from barcharts and immediately drop the use of stacked bar charts as those have generally been impossible to interpret as intended.  The data you display is continuous and I have to imagine that you envision a smooth curve representing the probability density function for each of the groups as well as the groups combined.
The replacement of bar charts for such continuous data has been around for some 65 years:  kernel density estimation.

If by the "contribution of each of these subgroups to the overall PDF" you mean the shape of the distributions of the individual groups and the overall PDF, you could construct the associated kernel density estimates from `SmoothHistogram`:

```
g1 = {5.2527, 4.72782, 4.38049, 3.49102, 3.72147, 3.33897, 3.95193, 
  3.569, 4.40854, 3.79908, 4.5764, 5.0339, 5.22894, 5.4027, 3.02539, 
  3.22868, 3.33291, 4.21609, 4.25765, 4.4448}
g2 = {3.83361, 3.86359, 3.81128, 4.1451, 3.8751, 3.80214, 6.21452, 
  4.15563, 4.54328, 4.3105, 4.45165, 4.61335, 4.41786, 4.62966, 4.88515}
g3 = {5.23026, 5.7992, 5.23549, 5.54506, 5.83686, 4.79847, 4.80319, 
  5.40646, 5.34246, 5.44923}

SmoothHistogram[{g1, g2, g3, Join[g1, g2, g3]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thin, Thin, Thick},
  PlotLegends -> {"Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "All Groups"}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Lag (ms)", "PDF"}]
```

[image: Kernel density estimates]

However, if by the "contribution of each of these subgroups to the overall PDF" you mean the contribution of each group to the overall PDF (which is just the sum of the individual contributions, then one can construct the display the contributions in the following manner:

```
(* Weights for each group as determined by the associated sample size *)
weight = Length[#] & /@ {g1, g2, g3}
weight = weight/Total[weight]

(* All data *)
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[Join[g1, g2, g3]]
(* Each group *)
{skd1, skd2, skd3} = SmoothKernelDistribution[#, skd["Bandwidth"]] & /@ {g1, g2, g3}

Plot[{weight[[1]] PDF[skd1, x], weight[[2]] PDF[skd2, x], weight[[3]] PDF[skd3, x], 
  PDF[skd, x]}, {x, 2, 7}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thin, Thin, Thick}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Group contributions to overall PDF", Bold, 18],
  PlotLegends -> {"Group 1 contribution", "Group 2 contribution", 
  "Group 3 contribution", "All Groups PDF"},
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Lag (ms)", "PDF"}]
```

[image: Contributions to overall PDF]

Why is this better than a stacked bar chart?  (1) You likely believe in an underlying smooth function for all groups and (2) the contributions are all readily evident as the contributions all start at the base at zero.  How can one possibly determine the contribution from group 3 (for instance) when the base of the bars are all over the place?  You'd had to do plenty of mental gymnastics to make that happen.